# How to make checkboxes appear conditionally in MUI Datatable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a MUI Datatable. While defining 'options' for the table, I am setting  `selectableRows: 'multiple', selectableRowsHeader: true,`
This creates a table with the checkboxes for all rows and also the selectall checkbox on top. However, I want it to appear only when I click a certain button in the title. How do i do this?
My code snippet is as follows

```
            columns={columns}
            options={{
              ...muiDataTableCommonOptions(),
              download: false,
              expandableRowsOnClick: false,
              search: false,
              page: currentPage,
              rowsPerPage: numberOfRows,
              count: serialsTotalCounts,
              selectableRows: 'multiple',
              selectableRowsHeader: true,
              onRowClick: (rowData, rowMeta) => console.log('onRowsSelect.', rowData, rowMeta),
              customToolbar: () => (
                <SerialsCustomToolbar
                  showAddSerialButton={false}
                  textSearched={(text) => {
                    //DISORIENTED_SERIALS_LISTING - optional callback to handle rendering while using search box
                    this.query['searchText'] = text;
                    this.setState({ initialized: false }, () => {
                      this.pages.limit = LIMIT_PAGINATION_MAX;
                      this.pages.offset = 0;
                      const query = Object.assign({}, this.query, this.pages);
                      this.updateQuery(query);
                    });
                  }}
```

This is is just the code relevant to the table options. How do i conditionally define those props for the table options element? I cant use if-else as this is jsx and inside the render().

Answer (score 0):

To make this work. you need to add `isRowSelectable` option to your table

```
const tableData = [];// your table data
const tableOptions: MUIDataTableOptions = {
  // ...your options
  isRowSelectable: (dataIndex) => {
    const rowData = tableData[dataIndex];
    // Put your logic to check whether the row is selectable or not.
  },
};

// You can put this css somewhere. For example: `table.tsx`
const theme = createTheme({
  MuiCheckbox: {
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
       '&.Mui-disabled': {     
         visibility: 'hidden',
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <MUIDataTable options={tableOptions} {...props} />
</ThemeProvider>
```